# spell checking richtextbox in winforms project

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, spell-checking

I have a WinForms project that contains a RichTextBox (RTB) written with VB
I have set ShortcutsEnabled = FALSE in the RTB
To use any Spell Checker I am guessing this would need to set to TRUE

That is NOT my question! I have been reading for way more hours than I care to admit
With the understanding that Spell Checking is easy if you have a ASP.Net OR WPF project
Well I don't so here are the three candidates from NuGet NONE of these candidates offer much help
**WeCantSpell.Hunspell** and **VPKSoft.SpellCheckUtility** and **NetSpell**

I am not asking for a recommendation
Because I can not find a tutorial and am clueless on how to implement these Add In's with code
As well as NOT knowing if they are compatible with WinForms
I even looked at this CP post
[CP LINK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265823/i-Spell-Check-and-Control-Extensions-No-Third-Pa)

**Just a suggestion how to use one of these Add In's OR how to add spell checking to the RTB?**

Comment: less than 2 mins googling.  Samples & documentation for all three https://github.com/aarondandy/WeCantSpell.Hunspell/ http://www.loresoft.com/The-NetSpell-project and https://www.vpksoft.net/dl-categoy/programming-samples

Comment: @Hursey Thanks the vpksoft download triggered a DO NOT download warning need further checking the other link needs further explanation still looking for code

Answer (score 1):

To achieve spell checking, you can try Nuget Package `NHunspell`.

First, you need to add "NHunspell" from "NuGet" and import it. The specific operation is as follows:

Right click the Reference and select "Manage NuGet Packages...", then type "NHunspell " in the search bar and install it:

[image]

Second step, you need to create a folder to store ".aff" and ".dic" like this.

[image]

Download the "zip" containing the corresponding file, you can access [this site](http://download.services.openoffice.org/contrib/dictionaries/).

Here is a demo you can refer to.

```
Private Sub btCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btCheck.Click
    Dim affFile As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "../../Dictionaries/en_us.aff"
    Dim dicFile As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "../../Dictionaries/en_us.dic"
    lbSuggestion.Items.Clear()
    lbmorph.Items.Clear()
    lbStem.Items.Clear()

    Using hunspell As New Hunspell(affFile, dicFile)
        Dim correct As Boolean = hunspell.Spell(TextBox1.Text)
        checklabel.Text = TextBox1.Text + " is spelled " & (If(correct, "correct", "not correct"))

        Dim suggestions As List(Of String) = hunspell.Suggest(TextBox1.Text)
        countlabel.Text = "There are " & suggestions.Count.ToString() & " suggestions"
        For Each suggestion As String In suggestions
            lbSuggestion.Items.Add("Suggestion is: " & suggestion)
        Next

        Dim morphs As List(Of String) = hunspell.Analyze(TextBox1.Text)
        For Each morph As String In morphs
            lbmorph.Items.Add("Morph is: " & morph)
        Next

        Dim stems As List(Of String) = hunspell.Stem(TextBox1.Text)
        For Each stem As String In stems
            lbStem.Items.Add("Word Stem is: " & stem)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

The result,

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: The Moon is high on my side of the EARTH So will test this on the Sun side Looking at the code I assume you used a TextBox and your code will still function with a Rich Text Box?Not sure what the Analyze word & Word Stem is about Need to understand what a .aff FILE is Thanks for taking the time for a detailed answer

Comment: You LINK for a dictionary is a little short on words I have been playing with this process in a JavaFX project and spent a lot of time searching for FREE dictionaries https://github.com/dwyl/english-words the words_alpha.txt and dictionary.txt offer many more words